# How can I create a create account details database for a user?

Tags: iot, developer-tools, thingworx

I have created a 'Login' mashup and a 'User Creation' mashup. What can I do to allow the user to save the details that they enter on the 'User Creation' mashup to some sort of back-end database, and then when they type in username and password on 'Login' mashup, it should verify and let them navigate to the next mashup. Basically, a basic login system on any website.

Answer (score 0):

Mashup sound like the wrong term here to me.
Mashups refer to combination of multiple services to one providing a larger functionality. In your example, as I understand it, you have a very basic services, that do not wrap or combine other services.

Regarding your specific scenario, I would have just added the missing logic you described to each of the services.
That is the 'User Creation' service would additionally store the user details to a database + perhaps a hash of the password, and the 'Login' service would authenticate the user by validating his details vs the database.

The server side of the 2 services should have access rights to the shared database.

I hope this answers your question.